# addEventListener for mousewheel (and other types) not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Need to implement a zoom in/out (and panning) function for the canvas element. This is my first attempt at JavaScript events, so my non-existent experience could be the issue here. I don't know if I'm using the types correctly. Used what I found online.

```
function onLoad() {
var canvas;
var context;
var exampleFamilyTrees;
var topPerson;
var previousMousePosition;
var mousePosition
var pan;
var mouseDown;
var zoom;   

function initialise() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (!canvas) {
        alert('Error: Canvas element not found');
        return;
    }

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
        alert('Error: Unable to get canvas context');
        return;
    }
    exampleFamilyTrees = new ExampleFamilyTrees();
    topPerson = exampleFamilyTrees.getFamilyTree(0);

    pan = new Vector(0, 0);
    zoom = 1;
    //context.translate(canvas.width*0.5, canvas.height*0.5);
}
function draw() {   
    context.save();
    context.translate(pan.getX(), pan.getY());
    context.scale(zoom, zoom);
    topPerson.draw(context);
    context.restore();
}

initialise();   

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false); 

function onMouseDown(event) {
    previousMousePosition = new Vector(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    mouseDown = true;
}
function onMouseUp(event) {
    mouseDown = false;
}   
function onMouseMove(event) {
    mousePosition = new Vector(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    if (mouseDown) {
        var difference = mousePosition.subtract(previousMousePosition);
        pan.add(difference);
    }
    previousMousePosition = mousePosition;
}

function onMouseWheel(event) {
    var wheelDelta = event.wheelDelta;
    if (wheelDelta > 0){
        zoom = zoom * 1.1;
    }
    else {
        zoom = zoom * 0.9;
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 1000/60);}
```

None of these functions work. I guess my syntax is wrong. Console doesn't complain at all.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `canvas`?

Comment: Inside onLoad() function. Same as this block of code.

Comment: Your `setInterval()` call should very likely be `setInterval(draw, 1000/60);`

Comment: @MarcMardare Add all the relevant code please.

Comment: are you getting any error in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Your events are being bound correctly, iv'e prepared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wadzeoL/) to demonstrate it, i've commented all the code regarding to `Vector` and`ExampleFamilyTrees` objects because I don't have the constructor functions of them (not sure if it's a library or something you've made) and also to make the example a little more simple, since the question is about the event handlers not working.

Before commenting out those lines, I had some errors in my console regarding those objects (`Vector`, `ExampleFamilyTrees`). Maybe You are also getting those errors and that's the reason why your events are not being bound.

If you check the console after running the fiddle, you can see the logs being displayed for each of the events you want to bind.